# Use of literal 'dquote' string in icalendar values

Tags: php, escaping, icalendar

I'm looking at an open-source PHP program which performs the following transformation to replace double-quote characters in string values:

```
$text = str_replace("\"", "DQUOTE", $text);
```

For example, the string `Call me "foo".`, after this transformation, would be represented in an icalendar DESCRIPTION field like so:

```
DESCRIPTION:Call me DQUOTEfooDQUOTE.
```

My reading of various online documentation (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt and its summaries at http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) indicate that this is incorrect, and the correct representation should be

```
DESCRIPTION:Call me \"foo\".
```

What is the correct representation?

Comment: Use a different program. This one seems to have misinterpreted the RFC. The RFC actually says `DQUOTE = %x22`

Comment: Maybe the library you're looking at does another replace later on?

Comment: Since it's open source i can submit a patch, once I'm clear on the correct interpretation.

Comment: @apokryfos, so the correct interpretation would be `DESCRIPTION:Call me %x22foo%x22.`?

Comment: @mkaatman, good thought, but I have observed the literal DQUOTE representation in the feed.

Comment: I think the `%x22` is just to say that it's a double quote in ASCII (e.g. `"`). If that's text then it needs to be escaped as you said, if it needs the double quote there then it should be a double quote.

Comment: In things like this you need to go through the spec thoroughly. Unfortunately there's no way around it. e.g. it says that `quoted-string      = DQUOTE *QSAFE-CHAR DQUOTE` which is the reason why text which contains double quotes needs to have them escaped since text can be presented as a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

The spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.3.11 indicates that double and single quotes need not be escaped at all, as does the example for the DESCRIPTION field (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.8.1.5), so the correct representation would be

```
DESCRIPTION:Call me "foo".
```

BTW, in the time since this question was asked, the affected open-source project has fixed this issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20350